# equivalent curl command from wget command

Tags: linux, curl

I contact you today because I'm looking for an equivalent command to

```
wget ​-qO-
```

but for CURL

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
curl -s "$url"
```

instead of

```
wget ​-qO- "$url"
```